# Change cell text with singleton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, singleton

I Have a singleton class that request values in my server, here is the class:

```
static ConsoleRequests *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (ConsoleRequests *)sharedInstance {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        usersOnline = @"0 Online";
    }
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(requestOnlineUsers) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    return self;
}
```

When app run for the first time, inside the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I start that class and every 5 seconds a new request is doing in my server:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [[ConsoleRequests sharedInstance] init];
});
```

Great, this code works very well (and I can see the value changing in console log), but I have a problem! I have a UITableViewController with an UILabel and I change the label value with the property inside my singleton:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    SideBarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SideBarTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.onlineU.text = [[ConsoleRequests sharedInstance] returnOnline];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem with this code is that the value of the label does not change every request made on my server, why this is happening? how can I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

```
//This should be declared in ConsoleRequests.h
@protocol ConsoleRequestsDelegate
@optional

- (void)requestOnlineUsersDidFinish;

@end

@interface ConsoleRequests:NSObject

@property (assign) id<ConsoleRequestsDelegate> delegate;

@end

//In the ConsoleRequest.m file
- (void)requestOnlineUsers {
    //Whatever is your implementation
    [self.delegate requestOnlineUsersDidFinish];
}

//In YourViewController.h which contains UITableView
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <ConsoleRequestsDelegate>

@end

//In YourViewController.m
- (void)requestOnlineUsersDidFinish {
    [self.tableView reload];
}
```

This should do the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Without refreshing the cell, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is not called. So you need to refresh the cell when you get a result from the request inside the singleton.

1. Make a UITableView property inside the ConsoleRequests.
2. Set table view object to the property appropriately.
3. When you get the result from the request update the cell of the table view.

Comment: While your suggestion will work, still in my opinion, the ConsoleRequests class should know nothing about a UI level class (in this case a UITableView). The responsibility of ConsoleRequests is only to make request to the server and get the result. One the other hand, if you have a delegate such that ConsoleRequestsDelegate which will have a method let's say requestOnlineUsersDidFinish and delegate can be the view controller where the table view has been added, then requestOnlineUsersDidFinish implementation will probably have to call [self.tableView reload] and that should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

How does the table view ever know about your requests? You should notify the controller of your tableview.

The typical approach here would be to make use of the [delegate pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html). Your `ConsoleRequests` should accept a weak reference to an object (in your case, your table view controller) that will be notified of a new request everytime it occurs. The reference could be declared as a weak property in the definition of `ConsoleRequests`:

```
@property (weak) id<ConsoleRequestsDelegate> delegate;
```

The delegate class should implement the `ConsoleRequest`'s delegate protocol, `ConsoleRequestsDelegate`, which you are responsible to define, probably in the same interface file as your class. Whenever a request is being handles, your class will call its delegates' method *.

Using delegation way the `ConsoleRequests` class need not know anything about the nature of it's delegate, and the delegate need not know about the inner workings of the `ConsoleRequests` class.

Alternatively, you could use [Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043-SW1), for a more loosely-coupled solution, but I would suggest delegation is a more suitable solution for your case.

<sub>*Don't forget to check whether the delegate actually implements the corresponding method, as per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11-SW29) – otherwise you may end up with a nasty `NSInvalidArgumentException` in your hands!</sub>